# AJAX not echoing through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Okay so I am trying to get the PHP to save the users data to the XML and then forward the user onto the homepage..but when the JavaScript is ran it does not grab the echo's at the end of the script along with the header();

The PHP i wish to echo

```
  echo "<b>Congratulations registration was Successful.<br /> Your Customer ID is: $id4</b>";
          echo "<br/>";
          echo "redirected automatically in 7 seconds";
            header( "Refresh:7; buyonline.htm", true, 303);
          $doc->save("data/customer.xml");
        }
```

And the JavaScript function

```
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
            var lastname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
            var number = document.getElementById("pNumber").value;
            var type = "";
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
              xHRObject.open("GET", "testregristation.php?firstName=" + firstname + "&lastName=" + lastname + "&email=" + email + "&password="+password+"&pNumber="+number, true);
              xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
                    {
                       document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText;
                    }
              xHRObject.send(null);
```

Obviously these are small snippets but i do not understand why it wont send the response to the screen it shows the response in "firebug".. my PHP also does a email check to make sure its not in use, and that echoes perfectly.

Comment: `xHRObject.status == 200` - you don't have the 200 status code in your response: `header( "Refresh:7; buyonline.htm", true, 303);` it's 303. - you never enter the part of javascript where you actually set the innerhtml. better use console.log for debugging. - also *ensure* you have PHP error logging properly setup, just in case you get some header warnings etc.

Comment: okay i changed it to 200...and it now pops up with the echo thank you...but i also have problems with the header not sending the user ? to buyonline.htm

Comment: the header is not sending any user at all, so it shouldn't. do you mean that the user is getting redirected? I guess so, so let me close that against the duplicate (knowing about the typo material that is correct now as you say).

Comment: yea sorry redirect.. its been an exhausting night trying to fix this up.. hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really tested your code to make sure that what I'm about to say is 100% right.
I never tried to use header in a way like this inside ajax response.
But, I guess that if you want to redirect the user just use javascript for that.

PHP:

```
echo "<b>Congratulations registration was Successful.<br /> Your Customer ID is: $id4</b>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "redirected automatically in 7 seconds";
$doc->save("data/customer.xml");
```

Javascript:

```
if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
{
    document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        window.location.pathname = "/buyonline.htm";
    }, 7000 /* 7 seconds */);
}
```

Edit:
Now because you using javascript to redirect the page, you could also countdown the seconds:

PHP:

```
echo "<b>Congratulations registration was Successful.<br /> Your Customer ID is: $id4</b>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "redirected automatically in <span id="redirect-countdown">7 seconds</span>";
$doc->save("data/customer.xml");
```

Javascript:

```
if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
{
    document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText;

    var countdown = document.getElementById("redirect-countdown");

    var count = 8;
    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        count--;

        countdown.innerText = count + " second" + (count > 1 ? "s" : "");

        if(count <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(interval); // Kill the interval timer
            window.location.pathname = "/buyonline.htm"; // Redirect to that page
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I have never changed a webpage using Javascript before, but this does not work... i did copy it word for word just incase i was meant to change a default value.

Comment: I just gave the main idea, I did not tested this code. but note that the window.location.href is the full address. Try to use pathname instead: window.location.pathname = "/buyonline.htm";